# Cannot enable APR Protocol on Embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-8, apr

I am trying to use the APR protocol in my Spring Boot project.

Till now i have downloaded the `tomcat-native` library and did what it instructed me to do, which are `./configure` , `make`  and `make install`. After that i copied all libtcnative files with different extensions to `/usr/lib`. Now Embedded Tomcat has found all tomcat-native files but it is not running tomcat using the `APR` protocol.

I have configured my project to run in `https` with a `letsencrypt` certificate in `http/2` and I am using `Ubuntu 16.04`, `Java 1.8.191`, `Spring Boot 2.0.7`. Below is my logtrace when my server starts:

```java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=44947 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:/home/samim/IntalledSoftware/idea-IU-173.4301.25/lib/idea_rt.jar=37149:/home/samim/IntalledSoftware/idea-IU-173.4301.25/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/root/IdeaProjects/templateprocessor/target/classes:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.10.0/log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.10.0/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/snakeyaml-1.19.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.7/jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.7/jackson-core-2.9.7.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.0.11.RELEASE/spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.7/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.7.jar:/root/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.8/micrometer-core-1.0.8.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.10/HdrHistogram-2.1.10.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/latencyutils/LatencyUtils/2.0.3/LatencyUtils-2.0.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.0.11.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.11.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/5.0.10.RELEASE/spring-security-config-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/5.0.10.RELEASE/spring-security-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.0.11.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4/3.0.4.RELEASE/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring5/3.0.11.RELEASE/thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/3.0.11.RELEASE/thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/attoparser/attoparser/2.0.5.RELEASE/attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/unbescape/unbescape/1.1.6.RELEASE/unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/thymeleaf/extras/thymeleaf-extras-java8time/3.0.2.RELEASE/thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.7/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.7.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.7/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.7.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.35/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.35.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.35/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.35.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.35/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.35.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.13.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.13.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.4/classmate-1.3.4.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.0.11.RELEASE/spring-web-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.11.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-devtools-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.11.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.0.11.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.0.10.RELEASE/spring-security-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar com.siqes.TemplateprocessorApplication
19:23:01.616 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
19:23:01.620 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter/target/classes/]
19:23:01.620 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/root/IdeaProjects/templateprocessor/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.7.RELEASE)

2018-12-26 19:23:02.067  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] com.siqes.TemplateprocessorApplication   : Starting TemplateprocessorApplication on dev-76 with PID 10929 (/root/IdeaProjects/templateprocessor/target/classes started by root in /root/IdeaProjects/templateprocessor)
2018-12-26 19:23:02.069  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] com.siqes.TemplateprocessorApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-26 19:23:02.158  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2690e06e: startup date [Wed Dec 26 19:23:02 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-26 19:23:04.260  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 443 (https) 80 (http)
2018-12-26 19:23:04.283  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-12-26 19:23:04.284  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.35
2018-12-26 19:23:04.288  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.19] using APR version [1.5.2].
2018-12-26 19:23:04.289  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2018-12-26 19:23:04.289  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
2018-12-26 19:23:04.292  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018]
2018-12-26 19:23:04.356  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-12-26 19:23:04.356  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2204 ms
2018-12-26 19:23:04.975  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-26 19:23:04.975  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webMvcMetricsFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-26 19:23:04.976  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-26 19:23:04.976  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-26 19:23:04.976  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-26 19:23:04.976  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-12-26 19:23:04.977  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpTraceFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-26 19:23:04.977  INFO 10929 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-12-26 19:23:05.150  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 7c0a25e1-aa1f-4b57-884f-94fbd8afc570

2018-12-26 19:23:05.267  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter      : Validated configuration attributes
2018-12-26 19:23:05.290  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter@c0cdb3d, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2b320338, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@325f68d3, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@48e85931, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@240e5c77, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@60808cc4, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@145d0cc7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@68485018, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@d3c6627, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@71d8532b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@787589ce]
2018-12-26 19:23:05.380  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-12-26 19:23:05.659  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2690e06e: startup date [Wed Dec 26 19:23:02 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-26 19:23:05.710  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.siqes.templateprocessor.controller.MainController.home()
2018-12-26 19:23:05.711  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/template-processor],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.siqes.templateprocessor.controller.MainController.templateProcessor()
2018-12-26 19:23:05.716  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-12-26 19:23:05.716  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-12-26 19:23:05.741  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-12-26 19:23:05.741  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-12-26 19:23:06.038  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2018-12-26 19:23:06.048  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-12-26 19:23:06.049  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-12-26 19:23:06.051  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-12-26 19:23:06.071  WARN 10929 --- [  restartedMain] on$ThymeleafSecurityDialectConfiguration : Auto-configuration for thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 is deprecated in favour of thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5
2018-12-26 19:23:06.126  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-12-26 19:23:06.168  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-12-26 19:23:06.611  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 443 (https) 80 (http) with context path ''
2018-12-26 19:23:06.616  INFO 10929 --- [  restartedMain] com.siqes.TemplateprocessorApplication   : Started TemplateprocessorApplication in 4.983 seconds (JVM running for 5.92)
2018-12-26 19:23:07.282  INFO 10929 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-26 19:23:07.282  INFO 10929 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-12-26 19:23:07.298  INFO 10929 --- [on(4)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 16 ms
```

My beans are as follows:

```java
@Configuration
public class ConnectorConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {

        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());

        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector redirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(80);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(443);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

I even tried using the AprLifecycleListener like below:

```java
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {

    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
            securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
            SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
            collection.addPattern("/*");
            securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
            context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
    };
    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());

    LifecycleListener aprLifecycleListener = new AprLifecycleListener();
    tomcat.setProtocol("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol");
    tomcat.addContextLifecycleListeners(aprLifecycleListener);

    return tomcat;
}
```

But i get error while starting tomcat with the APR:

```java
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.7.RELEASE)

2018-12-26 20:05:29.201  INFO 11939 --- [  restartedMain] com.siqes.TemplateprocessorApplication   : Starting TemplateprocessorApplication on dev-76 with PID 11939 (/root/IdeaProjects/templateprocessor/target/classes started by root in /root/IdeaProjects/templateprocessor)
2018-12-26 20:05:29.203  INFO 11939 --- [  restartedMain] com.siqes.TemplateprocessorApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-26 20:05:29.266  INFO 11939 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@57b72439: startup date [Wed Dec 26 20:05:29 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-26 20:05:31.222  WARN 11939 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: To use SSL, the connector's protocol handler must be an AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol subclass
2018-12-26 20:05:31.235  INFO 11939 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-12-26 20:05:31.244 ERROR 11939 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: To use SSL, the connector's protocol handler must be an AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol subclass
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:157) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) [spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) [spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.siqes.TemplateprocessorApplication.main(TemplateprocessorApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: To use SSL, the connector's protocol handler must be an AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol subclass
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.0.11.RELEASE.jar:5.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.SslConnectorCustomizer.customize(SslConnectorCustomizer.java:55) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeSsl(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:317) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.customizeConnector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:300) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:166) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I had to remove some lines as stackoverflow has a limit of 30000 character. I am posting it in a comment. Please Help.

Comment: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=35113 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true`

Comment: `20:05:28.752 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
20:05:28.756 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter/target/classes/]`

Comment: `20:05:28.756 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/root/IdeaProjects/templateprocessor/target/classes/]`

Comment: What is your Tomcat version? Why do you want to use APR?

Comment: @Christopher My embedded tomcat version is 8.5.35. Tomcat APR performs better in production environment.

Comment: Have you benchmarked against NIO and NIO2? The biggest performance improvement that APR used to give was access to the OpenSSL-based crypto engine. The NIO/NIO2 connectors can be used with OpenSSL, now. The native library is still required, though. It looks like Spring Boot doesn't like the APR connector itself, and requires the use of a JSSE-based connector (such as NIO/NIO2).